# Excel VBA - Open URL in the current instance of Firefox

Tags: excel, url, firefox, instance, vba

I found a way to open a link:

```
Shell "C:\Users\...\Firefox.exe" & " https://www.startpage.com", vbMaximizedFocus
```

The problem is that Excel tries to open this web page into a new instance of Firefox.
How could I force Excel to open it in the current instance?

Thank you

Comment: If FireFox is your default browser, simply shell execute the url to open in the current browser.

Comment: Firefox is not my default browser and I use a portable edition.

Comment: Well then, if there is an answer it will be [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Command_Line_Options).

Comment: How those command lines could work into Excel VBA?

Comment: @upltu the same way as you run Firefox with `Shell` like `Shell "…\Firefox.exe -command1 -command2"`

Comment: Gotcha. -new-instance opens a new instance of Firefox but it starts my home page instead of the URL.

Comment: I don't know what happens but using my first command works fine now. It opens the URL into the current instance.
Maybe -new-instance helped somehow.